# ¿Por qué el evento click no funciona?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menú, responsive

Sucede que estoy haciendo una navegación adaptable y cuando el navegador llega a cierta medida de pantalla las opciones desaparecen y en su lugar aparece un icono que se supone al hacer click sobre el deberían mostrar las opciones pero no sucede nada y según mi navegador no hay errores.

Este es mi código Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-MX">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Menu de Navegación Estandar</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="headerTop">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="mainNavbar">
               <div class="navbar__Icon" id="btnMenu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
                <ul class="navbar__menu" id="opcMenu">
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>  
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b4087b7348.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

este es mi JavaScript:

```
    'use strict'

function mostrarMenu() {
    var botonMenu = document.getElementById("btnMenu");
    var opcionesMenu = document.getElementById("opcMenu");
    var contador = 0;

    botonMenu.addEventListener('click', function() {

        if (contador == 0) {
            opcionesMenu.classList.add("menuShow");
            contador = 1;
        }else{
            opcionesMenu.classList.remove("menuShow");
            contador = 0;
        }

    });

   console.log("Funciona!");
}

window.onload = function() {mostrarMenu()};
```

Anteriormente en lugar de agregar o remover clases aplicaba los estilos directamente en javascript y de igual manera no me mostraba errores en la consola del navegador pero tampoco mostraba las opciones de la navegación.

Comment: "las opciones desaparecen y en su lugar aparece un icono que se supone al hacer click sobre el deberían mostrar las opciones pero no sucede nada", no son esos botones distintos?, por que ese es el sentido principal del porque no funcione.

Comment: El evento click funciona. Basta con mirar el inspector para ver que aparece y desaparece la class `menuShow`. Observación: en lugar de complicarte con lo del contador puedes utilizar el método `toggle`. Toggle = alternar conmutar. `opcionesMenu.classList.toggle("menuShow");`

Comment: Si, tambien pense lo mismo,  el click funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de usar un contador, mejor asigna clases al menú para ocultar / mostrar, iniciando en oculto.

Al terminar de cargar la página solo se asigna el evento `click` del botón y en `mostrarMenu()` buscas la clase actual del menú, si está oculto lo muestras y viceversa, quitando y agregando clase.

```js
'use strict'
function mostrarMenu() {
    let opcionesMenu = document.getElementById("opcMenu");
    if(opcionesMenu.className.indexOf('hideMenu') > -1) {
        opcionesMenu.classList.remove('hideMenu');
        opcionesMenu.classList.add('showMenu');
    } else {
        opcionesMenu.classList.remove('showMenu');
        opcionesMenu.classList.add('hideMenu');
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("btnMenu").addEventListener('click', mostrarMenu);
};
```

```css
#btnMenu { cursor:pointer; }
.hideMenu { display:none; }
.showMenu { display:block; }
```

```html
<header class="headerTop">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="mainNavbar">
               <div class="navbar__Icon" id="btnMenu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
                <ul class="navbar__menu hideMenu" id="opcMenu">
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>  
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b4087b7348.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Puede hacerse un poco más sencillo, evitando las comparaciones y cambiando las clases con `toggle()`:

```js
'use strict'
function mostrarMenu() {
    let opcionesMenu = document.getElementById("opcMenu");
    opcionesMenu.classList.toggle('hideMenu');
    opcionesMenu.classList.toggle('showMenu');
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("btnMenu").addEventListener('click', mostrarMenu);
};
```

```css
#btnMenu { cursor:pointer; }
.hideMenu { display:none; }
.showMenu { display:block; }
```

```html
<header class="headerTop">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="mainNavbar">
               <div class="navbar__Icon" id="btnMenu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
                <ul class="navbar__menu hideMenu" id="opcMenu">
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__Item"><a href="#" class="item__Link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>  
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b4087b7348.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```